# Delete common thing from pushed GitHub commits without deleting commit history

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit

I've pushed a file that has my email password to GitHub followed by many commits afterward. Each commit has my old data i.e. password. How can I delete my password from all commits?

Comment: Note that depending on your definition of "not deleting history", it's not possible.

Comment: This should work tolerably
 https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/content/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository.md